# How can I run operations on a set of dataframes with a for loop?

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, for-loop, concatenation

This is a general problem I'm having, but I'll use the Titanic dataset as an example. To allow for operations on both the train and test set together, I combined them:

```
combined = [train_df, test_df]
```

I also simplified the titles for each passenger, so each is now one of 8 possibilities. For both the train_df and test_df, I now want to make dummies for the 'Title' column, add them to the dataframes, and drop the original 'Title' column. The code I proposed is:

```
for df in combined:
    df = pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df.Title)],axis=1)
    df = df.drop('Title',axis=1)
```

These operations do work when I manually execute them on a single dataframe, but when running the for loop nothing is happening. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not working because you are modifying a copy of the variable in the list and never assign it back in the list.

For example:

```
a = [0,1,2,3]
for i in a:
    i = i+1
a
>>> [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

what you need is access the elements of the list:

```
 a = [0,1,2,3]
 for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = a[i]+1
 a
 >>> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

or in a simpler way:

```
a = [0,1,2,3]
a = [i+1 for i in a]
a
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So in your case:

```
for df in range(len(combined)):
    combined[df] = pd.concat([combined[df],pd.get_dummies(combined[df].Title)],axis=1)
    combined[df] = combined[df].drop('Title',axis=1)
```

or in a simpler way (index free using iterators)

```
combined = [pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df.Title)],axis=1).drop('Title',axis=1) for df in combined]
```

**EDIT**

It seems you have a misunderstanding on how the memory in python works and how you will update the variables.

let's take `a,b = 3,4` and `l = [a,b]` then changing a or b will **not** change l. Once created, it will live its life independently from a and b. So will you concatenation. Hence the fact that updating the list will no updates the variable used for its creation. You have to assign the new value to your variables. To do so, as you don't want the list to exists after using it, the best way is to do a function:

```
def my_func(df):
    df = pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df.Title)],axis=1)
    df = df.drop('Title',axis=1)
    return df
```

and then you apply it to the two dataframes:

```
train_df = my_func(train_df) 
test_df= my_func(test_df)
```

**Second Edit**:

So why did it worked? Well again is a question of how memory works in python and especially iterators. We will not go in detail but let's take an example with a list (similar to a dataframe here):

```
a = [[0,1],[2,3,4]]
for i in a:
    i.pop(0)
a
>>> [[1], [3, 4]]
```

You see that we have modify the variable inside the list. This is because we did not create at any point a named copy of the iterator. We modified in the memory the current object. So using the `Inplace=True` is doing exactly this. It is modifying the dataframe directly, not creating a copy of it.

Comment: OK, we're making progress, but I notice the following: train_df and test_df are still unchanged after executing your code, though combined[0] and combined[1] contain the right solution. This is confusing to me since actually train_df and test_df should be the same as combined[0] and combined[1], right? That's how the combined dataframe is defined in the beginning. Is it possible that in using range(len(combined)) somehow the labels of each df in combined is lost or something?

Comment: no it s not. You are wrong about how memory works. i ll update the answer for you to see this.

Comment: O wow, I had not idea! This solves my problem! Though I have one more follow-up question, also to explain where my confusion came from. Before, I apparently succeeded in dropping columns from each of the dataframes in "combined", as in, for example:

for dataset in combined:
    dataset.drop(['PassengerId'],axis=1,inplace=True)

Then calling train_df and test_df indeed showed them without PassengerId column. With the information I got from you I don't understand why it worked...

Comment: i ll update to answer this (if it solves your issue please accept the answer to close the question)